# Google Map Touch events on HP touch screen

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, touch, multi-touch

I'm developing a web app for an HP Compaq L2105tm touch screen on a windows 7 box.  When I bring up maps.google.com in Chrome the map works just fine with pinch zooming and other touch events you'd expect from a touch screen.  However, when I use the following code to do a basic google map embed, the touch events do not work as expected. (Pinch zoom does not work.)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        html, body, div#map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script>
        (function() {
            var div = document.getElementById('map');
            var lat = -36.5;
            var lng = 150.5;

            var options = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 8
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map( div, options );
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is why does maps.google.com work with pinch zoom and my map not work with pinch zoom in the exact same browser/touch environment?

**UPDATE**

This issue was handled in the bug

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824421

and was solved in version 3.27 of Google Maps JavaScript API in December 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the new api addresses this

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Mobile

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem and actually spoke with someone on the Google Maps Api team and they are aware of the issue.  Unfortunately, there is no timetable for when it will be addressed.  So I guess you can take solace in knowing that they know it is an issue.

Comment: Heck, I'm glad someone else on the internet knows what I'm talking about. I guess I'll be programming those touch events myself *sigh*